# Windows or browser, link alias

Tags: windows, firefox, alias

Is there an easy way to create link aliases under Windows (or at least Firefox). For example: I type `example.com` but want to retrieve data from `localhost/a/b/c/d/e/f`

Comment: Are you intending to manually do name resolution before your request is sent to DNS? If so, are you familiar with the hosts file?

Comment: The hosts file doesn't work in the way explained above. I just want a simple pointer.

Comment: Given that the first thing a browser does to a hostname is try to resolve it, I'm not sure how this could be done without manipulating DNS.

Comment: Well... it could read the shortcut I provide and read the host from it. I'm 100% sure it's possible to be done but can't find an approperiate add-on.

Comment: Ok. If you do, please submit it as an answer to this question! I'd like to know.